# How Two way Data binding hap[ens internally in Angular 2 and above

Tags: angular

I have searched a lot to understand, how the two way data binding internally works in Angular2 and above.  But not able to find out a simple clear cut answer.  Can some one help me to clarify this?

Comment: two way binding is basically property binding + event binding. https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html

Comment: Thank you Stavm.  This help me a lot.